# Redirect after log-in cannot work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form to manage the insertion of comments:

```
@model GatorsWebSite.Comment
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Comments", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ArticleID)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Text, new { @class = "form-control wide", @placeholder = "Type your comment", @rows = "3" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  }
```

This is the action on controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Text, ArticleID")] Comment comment){
  if (comment == null || comment.ArticleID <= 0)
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

  if (ModelState.IsValid){
    comment.Date = DateTime.Now;
    comment.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    _commentRepository.Add(comment);
    _commentRepository.Save();
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Details", "News", new { ID = comment.ArticleID });
}
```

Since the action is under authorization, if the user is not logged in

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl){
      if (ModelState.IsValid){
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null){
          await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
          return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else{
          ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
      }
      return View(model);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

the redirect url will be Comments/Create and will fail with a 404 error, does exist a general solution to manage this problem, since I cannot use a simple redirect to action?

Comment: when you are submitting the form the target action is not calling its giving 404 not found????

Comment: @Kartikeya I have updated my question with the screen of error

Comment: instead of `return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);`  try `return RedirectToAction("Create","Comments");`

Comment: the return url connot be the same everytime, so you suggest to parse the url, because doesn't exist a general solution to this scenario?

Comment: So the [GET]Create isn't authenticated correct?

Comment: @Bigfellahull the problem is the form in the original [POST] which seems discarded after the redirection to login action, I think I can only redirect to Index

Comment: One alternative is to make a create get action and make it redirect to articles list page.

Comment: @AshishCharan hey can you add an answer based upon your comment? I would like choose it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to make a `Create` get action and make it redirect to articles/news list page. For Example:

```
public ActionResult Create(){
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "News");
}
```

**EDIT**

and is exactly what I've done:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Text, ArticleID")] Comment comment)
    {
      if (comment == null || comment.ArticleID <= 0)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        comment.Date = DateTime.Now;
        comment.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        _commentRepository.Add(comment);
        _commentRepository.Save();

      }

      return RedirectToAction("Details", "News", new { ID = comment.ArticleID });
    }
```

...and work like a charm